# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Tags: php

Tried a few things, I am sure this is a minor error but I have been staring at it for ages!

```
if (isset ($_GET['id']) { $product_id = strip_tags($_GET['id']); }
```

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Comment: what's the language? PHP?

Comment: `if (isset ($_GET['id']))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a `)`:

```
if (isset ($_GET['id'])) { $product_id = strip_tags($_GET['id']); }
                       ^
```

Comment: Of course, what and idiot I am!

Answer (score 2):

you are missing first started small bracket.

```
(isset ($_GET['id']) -- here ) should be closed like.

if (isset ($_GET['id'])) { $product_id = strip_tags($_GET['id']); }
```

Comment: uhh.. what is a "first started small bracked"? Did you mean "first opening parenthesis"?

Comment: none that Kal has already said the same